# Spring MVC: how do I configure a web app to call a controller by default?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'd like my Spring application to call a controller whenever someone opens the application at the root, like this:

```
http://server.com/myapp
```

or

```
http://server.com/myapp/
```

Ideally, I'd like the user to automatically be taken to `/home.do`, as in:

```
http://server.com/myapp/home.do
```

When I updated web.xml to include /home.do in the `<welcome-file-list>`, Tomcat returns an error page displaying:

```
The requested resource (/myapp/) is not available.
```

When I change `<welcome-file-list>` to instead take the user to the JSP behind home.do, the page loads, but the JSTL tags in the page cannot access a properties file that is loaded by my Spring configuration.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an html page or jsp add it to `<welcome-file-list>` and add this to the code of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://server.com/myapp/home.do" />
```

File list makes the page your default page and redirect will send to your controller without user notice

Comment: Or header with redirect code('location'). Or spring-MVC redirect view. This is correct answer. +1

Comment: I saw that solution here, but thought it was a bit low-tech for a Spring MVC app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252065/spring-mvc-how-to-create-a-default-controller-for-index-page I'll go ahead and do this.