# can't access to html file tomcat

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have an html file in my app root folder, which is located under `webapp` tomcat folder: `apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M3\webapps\shop\index.html` 
when I'm trying to open `http://localhost:8080/shop/`

> "The requested resource is not available"

occurs.  I'm using spring mvc, so I'm getting the following message in terminal: `No mapping for http request with URl shop/ in DispatcherServlet.` Nevertheless it works fine if rename it to index.jsp

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/362081/Servlets/java/Tomcat-requested-resource I think that it could be helpful to you ;)

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/shop/index.html
I think you have not mentioned the welcome file list under web.xml file in webapps/WEB-INF

Comment: The response is this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252065/spring-mvc-how-to-create-a-default-controller-for-index-page